# csh shell read .tshrc rather than .cshrc startup file

Tags: shell, csh, tcsh

I use csh shell ($ echo shell -> /bin/csh) and this time I added a environment variable $path to .csh file. However, every time when log in I need to source the .cshrc file to make this environment variable "activate" and appear after inputing "echo $PATH".

Then I try to set the environment variable in .tcshrc file, it works. Why?

My shell is CSH, so in principle should be work when environment variables is set in the .cshrc file.

If I am excuting .tcsh file rather than .csh file, how to make my csh shell run .csh file?

My OS: CentOS7

Comment: What happens if you rename/delete `.tcshrc` entirely? If that file is being sourced, then your `csh` would appear to be `tcsh`, which will read from `.tcshrc` if it exists instead of `.cshrc`.

Comment: (E.g., `csh --version` on my macOS box outputs `tcsh 6.21.00 ...`. `/bin/csh` is not a link to `/bin/tcsh`, but nevertheless *is* a `tcsh` executable.)

Comment: Note that tcsh is the dominant "modern" version of csh (to the very limited extent that there exists such a thing at all).

Comment: Both `csh --version` and `tcsh --version` output `tcsh 6.18.01 (Astron)....` on my Linux. @chepner

Comment: I'm pretty sure than that you are executing `tcsh`, not `csh`.  You did not say what OS you are using. For instance on my Mac `stat -f %i /bin/csh` and `stat -f %i /bin/tcsh` display the same inode number, which means that they are the identical binary.

Comment: My OS is centos7. Why `tcsh` and `csh` have run the identical binary? Is there any way to make these two different? @user1934428

Comment: I think many package maintainers see no point in supplying a separate `csh`, so there is only one binary. Since nearly nobody is using csh or tcsh anymore nowadays, they only install tcsh and make sure, that an invocation of csh does not crash, for those people who have old csh scripts to run. If you really want a "genuine csh", perhaps you can recompile it for your centos.